# How do I tell paperclip to not save the original file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How do I tell Paperclip not to save the original file when it is uploaded? Or even better, to store a scaled version of the file as the original?

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467130/rails-4-and-paperclip-stop-the-original-style-file-upload-to-copy-it-from-an/25585186)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe that you can simply define a style for :original to have paperclip replace the original with that size.

```
:styles => { :original => '300x168>', :cropped_thumb => {:geometry => "115x70#", :jcrop => true}, ...}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you, Chris. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 4):

Cris G's solution may be nice at most simple cases but it has limitations.
consider that: style :original Paperclip process first of all others, so after that updated :original image (much smaller now) will be the source for following processing.
Hence you are forced to keep :original style as best-resolutioned.
The situation comes worse as you need to crop images with processor: that is the situation where you really need for real original quality. )

So I would recommend you somewhat raw (need to find out how to get every attachments of the model) solution:

```
after_save :reprocess_attach

private

def reprocess_attach
    if self.<atch_name>.present? && Pathname.new(self.<atch_name>.path).exist?
        self.<atch_name>.save
        File.unlink(self.<atch_name>.path)
    end
end
```

it doesn't care about what processing was behind the stage. It just kills original file )

Comment: You are absolutely right, overriding the geometry of :original impacts the processing of all the others. But could you explain your solution to stopping the original from being uploaded in more detail please, I'm confused! Thanks!

Comment: @Sujimichi well, after save, the "reprocess_attach" checks if the attachment exists as original file. If it does, it ensure that all files are flushed in filesystem (save) and after deletes the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip always saves an original by default, but I 'believe', that if you just remove it from your migration then it will not try and save it.

I save a scaled original on my model so that users can edit their image later. My model looks like this :

```
:styles => { :cropped_thumb => {:geometry => "115x70#", :jcrop => true}, :resized_thumb => {:geometry => "115x70>"}, :deal => {:geometry => "64x56#"},  
:cropped_large => {:geometry => "#{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH}x#{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT}#", :jcrop => true},
:resized_large => {:geometry => "#{PHOTO_IMAGE_WIDTH}x#{PHOTO_IMAGE_HEIGHT}>"},

:orig => '300x168>',  #this is the scaled original that I call later


:cropped_orig => {:geometry => '300x168#', :jcrop => true},
:resized_orig => {:geometry => '300x168>'} },
:processors => [:jcropper]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Trip.