# Rails and Paperclip... don't save the original image, just the styles?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip, bandwidth

In paperclip when you save an image with lots of style and sizes it also saves the original.

But in my app it's not necessary to save the original, just the style will do, what I was wondering was how do you not save the original. Just store it in memory or in a temporary area and then not save it once the style have been generated.

Ideally it would not save original at all. I guess one solution would be to save the original, process the style and delete afterwards, however I'm trying to save on bandwidth and deleting the original after it has been saved kindof defeats the point.

Cheers!

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25467130/rails-4-and-paperclip-stop-the-original-style-file-upload-to-copy-it-from-an/25585186)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me

```
def destroy_original
  File.unlink(self.photo.path)
end
```

Taken from here: <del>http://tekn0t.net/delete-original-image-when-using-papercliprai</del>

**Edit:** the provided link is no longer valid. Here is a valid one from the same author: https://gist.github.com/tekn0t/755593

Answer (score 8):

check this: [How do I tell paperclip to not save the original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219787/how-do-i-tell-paperclip-to-not-save-the-original-file)

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, if your cropping something and the original is smaller than a different style then this doesn't work.