# Rails, Paperclip and S3. Avoid saving the original image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using Paperclip + s3 for image attachment. Is there a way to only store the styles and not the original image(in an attempt to reduce attachment save time and save storage space)?

I have seen a couple of post which suggest to use original as one of the style. It is not possible for me to do so, as i need the original to act as a reference for cropping.
Link to one such post: [How do I tell paperclip to not save the original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219787/how-do-i-tell-paperclip-to-not-save-the-original-file)

And also it is not possible to save original & delete it later as it kind of defeats the purpose.

Is there a setting which I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had the same question and I went briefly through the source code of paperclip. Please, underline "briefly". From what I understood, there is no possibility not to save the original. One who is experienced in understanding and experimenting with ruby, could override some methods in the paperclip "Filesystem" module (or "Fog", or "s3", depending on your implementation) to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good resource here: [Rails and Paperclip... don't save the original image, just the styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771615/rails-and-paperclip-dont-save-the-original-image-just-the-styles)

**Delayed**

In light of your findings & comment, you may wish to move the image processing to a backend job? Although I've not done this myself, there are resources such as the [delayed_paperclip gem](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip/) which allow you to push the processing part of Paperclip to a backend job

---

**System**

A note on system setup - I would personally accomodate the original image. If you're quibbling over storage space, unless you're facebook or instagram, your image space is not going to cause a big problem, especially considering [S3 pricing](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) is based on `TB`

Comment: Moving to delayed job will reduce delay, agreed. But this is part of user avatar upload and so cannot move it into separate thread as response is expected to include attachment's url.