# Remove exif from original image uploaded using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, exif

I have a post model which contains a image in three styles(thumb, small, original).

I want to remove the exif from every image created by paperclip, so I use "-strip" in the convert_options, but later found the exif still exists in the original style.

What can I do to remove it?

```
has_attached_file :image, {
  styles: { thumb: ["250x250>", :jpg], small: ["125x125>", :jpg] },
  convert_options: { all: "-quality 80 -interlace Plane -strip" }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

original style will always contain original image, no matter what. 
What you can do is to create an additional style, like `original-no-exif`, and then remove the real original image (you can do it this way: [Rails and Paperclip... don't save the original image, just the styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771615/rails-and-paperclip-dont-save-the-original-image-just-the-styles))

Comment: Assigning blank string to "original-no-exif" makes paperclip create a same size image, but the syntax is weird. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: I don't thinks so. Maybe you can even create "original" style, like pointed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219787/how-do-i-tell-paperclip-to-not-save-the-original-file