# How to upload only thumb image folder under system directory using paperclip in ruby on rails

Tags: paperclip

I have 5,00,000 Images to be upload using paperclip plugin. it will take more space that is, 9GB. but, i need to create only thumb folder under public/system/photos/1/thumb without original folder. How to figure out this issue?. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the answers suggested here: [How do I tell paperclip to not save the original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219787/how-do-i-tell-paperclip-to-not-save-the-original-file)

Comment: Thanks, Frankie Roberto. I have other issue that is, i need to remove image files under public/system/photos using rake task?