# Upload CSV and process with Paperclip without saving the CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, paperclip

I am currently allowing users to upload CSV files, processing them, saving database entries based on the content, and then having to go back and clean-up the CSV.  I'm wondering if it's possible to upload, and process by keeping the CSV in memory without it touching the disk?

[How do I tell paperclip to not save the original file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219787/how-do-i-tell-paperclip-to-not-save-the-original-file)

...seems to suggest that leaving the field off the migration will do this but I haven't had luck with this approach.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of paperclip *is* to save the file. You could have something like the following as your action and completely skip the use of paperclip.

```
def upload
  CSV.parse(params[:file].read) do |row|
    # do whatever you need to do with the row
  end
end
```

with a form like this:

```
<%= form_tag('/path/to/upload') do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thats a good point.  Was utilizing paperclip primarily because it gave me a bunch of helpers to check mimetypes, filesizes, etc.